# Finding all real solutions to $ \sqrt{x^2-p}+2\sqrt{x^2-1}=x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, radical-equations

This is a contest problem. It asks for all the real solutions of

$$
\sqrt{x^2-p}+2\sqrt{x^2-1}=x
$$

for arbitrary real $p$.

From the eq. it's clear that $p$ cannot be negative. By squaring once, splitting the radicals from the other terms and squaring again, I found a formula for $x^2$:

\begin{equation*}
x^2 = 1+\frac{p^2}{16(1-p/2)}.
\end{equation*}

From here we have $p<2$ for the second radical to be defined, and by comparing this expression with $p$ we get that $p<2$ makes the first radical be defined as well. Yet solutions of the original equation can only be found when $p\leq 4/3$, and $4/3$ is the (double) root of $9p^2-24p+16=0$ (obtained from comparing $1+\frac{p^2}{16(1-p/2)}$ with $p$).

I don't understand why this happens. Perhaps I've done something wrong. If I haven't, I'd appreciate any help in proving that there are no solutions if $p$ is greater than $4/3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When solving equations, by doing algebra like squaring etc, one could potentially include more solutions than the original equation.

For instance

$x = 1$ implies $x^2 = 1$, by squaring.

The second equation also has $x = -1$ as a solution, which is not a solution of the first one.

In your case, when you square etc, you might lose constraints like $x \ge 1$ and $x^2 \ge p$.

I suppose when you squared, you had the term $x - 2\sqrt{x^2 -1}$.

The constraint that $x \ge 2 \sqrt{x^2-1}$ (i.e. $x^2 \le 4/3$) gives us the constraint that $p \le 4/3$.

As you noticed,

$1 + \frac{p^2}{16(1-p/2)} -p \ge 0$ for all $p$.

Thus

$1 + \frac{p^2}{16(1-p/2)} \le 4/3$ implies that $0 \le 1 + \frac{p^2}{16(1-p/2)} -p \le 4/3 - p$ which implies $4/3 \ge p$.

Comment: thank you. I'm still confused, since 1+... >= p, 0<p<2 is satisfied for all p in [0,2). http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[{1+%2B+p^2/(16*(1+-+(p/2))),+p},+{p,+0,+3}]  Anyway I'm probably doing something very wrong. Thank you in advance for any further clarification.

Comment: @Welt: I have updated the answer. I had a mistake in algebra earlier.

Comment: very well, thank you. This problem struck me as somewhat odd.

Comment: you stole my rep!  And you have more than you know what to do with.  I had my answer typed up and was 15 sec from posting when yours hit.  Turned out you had covered everything I had to say, and more clearly.   Good answer.

Comment: @Ross: Thanks! Sorry about the wasted effort.